# Ubuntu crashing after a few on & off cycles

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a HP Pavillon with 16G of RAM, SSD 500G, i5 and Nvidia 950GTX, on which I recently installed a dual-boot by shrinking the partition in Windows, then using rufus and a usb key (My Windows 10 serves as my daily driver and Ubuntu is meant for work and in order to connect to a remote server).

It installed and ran without a problem.

But after several on & off cycles and installation of programs, I started to have big freezes. I was forced to turn the computer off manually.

After doing so, however, when I chose Ubuntu in grub once again, I got the following infinitely looping message on screen (looping so fast it was barely readable):

```
pcieport 000:00:1c.5: PC device BusError security=corrected type=Physical1Layer (Receiver ID) [ 0]x806 error statues=corrected mask=0000200
```

What I did then was to reinstall Ubuntu three times in a row, varying between 19.04 and 18.04, ran updates each time, checked that there was enough disk space.

I googled and found out about adding `pci=nomsi/noaer` to grub. This solution did not help.

Does anyone know what's going on?

EDIT: as requested, the kernel version:

```
4.19.0-5-amd64
```

And the result of lspci:

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
```

I have to precise i changed for Debian: but the error occured again after i manually installed the Wifi driver (it was missing). We had to blacklist the module to make my computer work normally again.

Comment: doesn't it sound to you like a damaged component? maybe the graphics card? that's what it sounds like to me. I know you said it boots fine on windows but perhaps the lesser nature of the ubuntu graphics driver means it isn't able to correct as many errors.

Comment: There is actually a probleme with my graphic crad, wich i just noticed thanx to your comment. I am trying to fix it and will keep you updated. Also thanx for the edit.

Comment: I fixed the problem, but it shows the same error.

Comment: What kernel version is reported when you run `$(uname -r)`?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lspci` and I'll take a look. What did you fix on your graphics card? Does Windows work ok? Remove pci=nomsi/noaer

Comment: I had the error 0x0003 with GeForce, which can lead to a disastrous situation. I tried several solutions but finally reinstalled the software GeForce to solve it. Apparently the otpion "allow interaction with the dekstop" of the Nvidia telemetry service can prevent linux from working fine.